# Return a Child Promise func for a variable in Parent Promise func?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I have an issue with a Promise function. I use **NodeJS + sequelizeJS**

I have a Child Promise function to get `User Data` in table `auth_user`:

```
function sequelize_user (id_in) {
  var promises = []
  var querydb = `SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id IN (${id_in})`;
  promises.push(
    db.sequelize.query(querydb, { type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(res => {
      return res
    })
  )
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

And I have a Parent Promise function to get Conversation, which have participants as a User.

```
function sequelize_conversation (conversation_id, req) {
  var promises = [];
  for (let id of conversation_id) {
    promises.push(
      db.ConversationPerson.findAll({ where: {'conversation_id': id, 'user_id': { [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id }} })
      .then(participants => {
        if (cvs_person.length) {
          return {
            'conversation_id': id,
            'with_user': (function() {
             sequelize_user(cvs_person.user_id)
              .then(user => {
                console.log(user) // -> { id: 1, username: 'feedgit' }
                return user // -> {} ?????????
              })
            })()
          }
        } else {
          return { 'conversation_id': id }
        }
      })
    );
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

In this code:

```
'with_user': (function() { sequelize_user([participants[0].user_id]) .then(user => { console.log(user); return user }) })()
```

I want to get `User` by using Child Promise function `sequelize_user` but it returns `{}`. This is not true.

What's wrong with my code? I think it's because wrong Promise Function Calling.

Comment: For starters, you state that `user` is  `{ id: 1, username: 'feedgit' }`. This is not true because it returns an array. You're not returning anything from IIFE, that's the problem, just don't use IIFEs where you don't need them. How did you test that `return user[0]` is `{}`? `with_user` is `undefined` in the code you posted.

Comment: why are you using an array for a single promise? - also `.then(res => {
      return res
    })` is redundant and not required at all

Comment: `console.log(user) // -> { id: 1, username: 'feedgit' }` I very much doubt it ... it would be `[{ id: 1, username: 'feedgit' }]`

Comment: `I want to get User by using Child Promise function sequelize_user but it returns {}` - I see now why you've made the code so overcomplicted - you're trying to do the impossible, turn asynchrony synchronous

Comment: See if [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8Pmu198w) works - not going to bother with an answer if it doesn't :p

Comment: @JaromandaX let me give you a trick question (if you feel like it) - when is `.then(res => { return res })` _not_ a no-op?

Comment: @JaromandaX since promises recursively assimilate - if `res` was a promise then it would not have reached the `then` to begin with: `Promise.resolve().then(() => Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1)))` is just `Promise.resolve(1)` after all, and `then`ing it unwraps the value, it's a bit tricker than that :)

Comment: Think things that are not promises but still undergo resolution and what one might do to them to cause edge-case behaviour.

Comment: No, we are not (about generators) - but you are right I was out of place to start an offtopic discussion, feel free to ping me in [the JS chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)  to continue :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for

```
db.ConversationPerson.findAll({
  where: {'conversation_id': id, 'user_id': { [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id }} 
}).then(participants => {
  if (cvs_person.length) {
    return sequelize_user(cvs_person.user_id).then(user => {
//  ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^
      console.log(user) // -> { id: 1, username: 'feedgit' }
      return {
//    ^^^^^^^^
        conversation_id: id,
        with_user: user,
//                 ^^^^
      };
    });
  } else {
    return { 'conversation_id': id }
  }
})
```

Comment: Could also do `async participants => {
  return Object.assign(
    { conversation_id: id },
    cvs_person.length
      ? { with_user: await sequelize_user(cvs_person.user_id) }
      : { }
  );
}` if their Node.js version supports ES2017.